# Is there a way to cut a speech video into parts on silences automatically?

Tags: video

As an English teacher, and also a programmer, I've created a system of listening that works this way:

I choose an interesting video full of speech.
**I manually cut it into peices based on slinces where there is no speech** (By silence I'm referring the the parts where speaker pauses for a second to breathe. The very very tiny pause between sentences)
I use transcription services to extract text of each part
And many other steps...

As a software programmer I hate manual operations. I don't like the idea of splitting a video into parts by hands. It really is a time consuming and dirty job.

Googling around I couldn't find anything. Is it possible to do that? How?

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://video.stackexchange.com/q/16967/1871

Comment: Dirty job! Them's fightin' words, pilgrim.  Joking aside, you're going to have to listen to the whole thing after you process it and fix mistakes anyway.  Might as well do it right the first time.  If it's too time consuming for you, hire someone or get a student to do it.

Comment: This reminds me of a question on superuser, where he used audacity to monitor the noise his kids made. When it got too loud the screen would switch off.

Comment: @Mulvya, thanks for your other answer. Very similar to what I want. I split the video into segments of 1 second, and guess what, mean_volume result was the same for all of'em. I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: Can you upload a sample which contains both speech and silence?

Comment: Yeah, as a sample we can analyze [this ted talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/josh_luber_the_secret_sneaker_market_and_why_it_matters)

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/8tBd6a8F

Comment: Pastebin has a limit, so I have only pasted the first half of the log.

Comment: So, apparently I'm doing something wrong. I have to find it out. Thank you for the precious work.